# GWT Widget Library - Source not translatable

Tags: java, gwt, module

I'm trying to create a *GWT* widget module. Right now, it has a single widget, just for testing. I try to include this module in a different project, and I get:

```
No source code is available for type com.company.gwt.client.components.VerticalDiv; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

In my main project module.gwt.xml I have:

```
<module>
    <!-- Google Modules -->
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
    <inherits name="com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.Crypto" />

    <inherits name="com.company.gwt.GWT_Library" />

    <entry-point class="com.company.app.client.App" />

    <source path="" />

    <resource path="resources" />

    <!-- Only support recent browsers -->
    <set-property name="user.agent" value="ie10,gecko1_8,safari" />
</module>
```

The GWT_Library xml sits in com.company.gwt and looks like this:

```
<module>       
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.resources.Resources" />

    <source path="client" />
    <resource path="client" />
</module>
```

The project structure:

```
.
+-- pom.xml
+-- src
|   +-- main
|       +-- java
|           +-- com
|               +-- company
|                   +-- gwt
|                       +-- client
|                           +-- components
|                               +-- VerticalDiv.java
|       +-- resources
|           +-- com
|               +-- company
|                   +-- gwt
|                       +-- GWT_Library.gwt.xml
|                       +-- client
```

I know that the main project is including it because if I change the **inherits** line in the module.gwt.xml, it gives me an error that it can't find it.

Here is the VerticalDiv class:

```
package com.company.gwt.client.components;

import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.HasClickHandlers;
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerRegistration;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel;

public class VerticalDiv extends FlowPanel implements HasClickHandlers
{
    public VerticalDiv()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler)
    {
        return this.addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
    }
}
```

This class used to sit in my main project, and it worked fine there. I have another module called "Shared", and it works fine as well. Though, this package does not have anything that can be used in UiBinder. I think that may be the difference. The VerticalDiv class is referenced in UI binders, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
             xmlns:e="urn:import:com.company.app.client.widgets"
             xmlns:c="urn:import:com.company.gwt.client.components"
>
    <ui:style>
        <!-- styling -->
    </ui:style>

    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <c:VerticalDiv>
            <e:LinkButton ui:field="viewAll" text="All Notifications"></e:LinkButton>
        </c:VerticalDiv>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

As you can see, I'm also using a widget from the main project, and it works correctly in this manner.

Is there something I'm missing for my module widgets to be usable in UiBinder files?

Comment: Many times, the message `No source code is available for type (...); did you forget to inherit a required module?` means that your Java class failed to be compiled by GWT. I get it all the time whenever I forget that GWT 2.6 does not support Java 8 syntax, or when I have multiple ui.xml's for the same Widget and add a new field only to one of them. Check the GWT compilation log, the actual error should be a couple (dozen) lines before that one.

Comment: That's a nice thought, but this is the first error that occurs in the build logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error turned out to be more accurate than anticipated...

I'm building with maven, so to make this work, I had to:

1. Generated a sources jar. So in the widget module pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

2. Include the sources in my main project pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <artifactId>gwt-library</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company.gwt</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <artifactId>gwt-library</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company.gwt</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

So, the error was correct. The source code was indeed not available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a descriptor for your "components" module, e.g. MyComponents.gwt.xml, in your com.company.gwt directory. Then you need to inherit it in your main module xml:

```
<inherits name="com.company.gwt.MyComponents"/>
```

This MyComponents.gwt.xml can be very simple (depending on which GWT modules it uses):

```
<module>

  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N'/>
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.resources.Resources"/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

</module>
```

Comment: I have this file. The contents of it are in my OP, under the main module.gwt.xml

Comment: Your file does not inherit anything from GWT, while your components use GWT packages.

Comment: I added the User and Resources inherits lines and that didn't make a difference. Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Comment: You have two different com.company.gwt packages. So the compiler looks into java.com.company.gwt, where your components are, and it cannot find your gwt.xml file there.